# Web browser not displaying the index.html in the htdocs directory - Apache

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, webserver, centos

The installation path of my Apache web server is `/usr/local/apache2`.

I start the server using a `apachectl start` command and when i type `localhost` in my Web Browser it displays a *Apache 2 Test Page powered by CentOS* and not the `index.html` in `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`. Does any one know the reason for this?

Also there are two `conf.d` files in my system. One is in `/etc/httpd/conf` and other one is in `/usr/local/apache2/conf` (where i installed Apache). Any reasons for this? Please help

Comment: Have you installed apache2 from source?

Comment: @sgmart yes installed according to this - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html.

Comment: Is there a special reason for that?. I just ask because centos repositories provide the compiled package (rpm) ready to install

Comment: No, there weren't any special reasons for installing Apache from source i just did for learning purposes and Yes i found out That `httpd` package already installed in my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I'm guessing you have built apache from source - was there a specific reason for doing this? I usually find systems are a lot more manageable if you use the standard distribution packages or use new packages from other repos if you need later versions.

If you don't have a specific need for using locally-built apache, I'd recommend removing it then installing apache using the normal CentOS repositories.

Next (or first, if you are staying with the locally-built apache), run: `httpd -V`

For example, one of my systems returns:

```
[me@here ~]# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Jun  6 2012 10:00:36
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:3
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Compiled using: APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

The output will tell you where its true config file is, in this case /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf - that way you'll know which config is the one actually being used.

Once you know which config files are being used, you can check them to see where the document root is - it might be in `/var/www/html/` instead of `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs` or just about anywhere.

When you know where the document root is, then check and make sure the files and directories are readable by apache (or whatever user apache is running as - the first column from `ps aux | grep httpd` will tell you that)

Next check the logfiles, typically `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and also the system logs in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/secure`

Lastly, if you are running a recent CentOS which has SELinux enabled, and you have built apache yourself you'll almost certainly be in a world of pain. You can try `getenforce` to see if SELinux is active, and `setenforce 0` to disable it (for testing).

Comment: Thanks for your answer agittins. Yes i installed Apache from source and it was already installed in my system by default. Therefore i did a `yum remove httpd` and used the version which i installed from source. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There was no special reason for installing Apache from source just did for learning purposes.

Comment: No worries @chamarakera, one thing I've learned over the years is that it is always easier to try and do things the way the distro you're using does things. This means either using their packages or taking the time to learn how to build packages yourself. It's not too bad with apache except it means that if you want PHP you'll have to build it from source too, AFAIK.